# Order of the differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The order of the differential equation whose general solution is given by $y = (C_{1} + C_{2})\cos (x + C_{3}) - C_{4} e^{x+ C_{5}}$ where $C_{1},C_{2}, C_{3}, C_{4}, C_{5}$ are arbitrary constants, is.......

This equation can be written as $A \cos (x + B) - C e^{x}$, so the order should be $3$ since there are $3$ arbitrary constants. But the answer is given $2$.

Without finding out the whole differential equation, how would I know the order of differential equation$?$

Answer (score 3):

I would also say that the answer is $3$. The general solution of the equation
$$y'''(t)-y''(t)+y'(t)-y(t)=0$$
is
$$y(t)=M \cos(t)+N\sin(t)+Ke^t$$
since $\{\cos(t),\sin(t),e^t\}$ is linearly independent.
This, in fact, can also be expressed as
$$y(t)=A\cos(t+B)+Ce^t.$$